# Higher Order Filters

Tags: circuit-analysis, amplifier, low-pass, active-filter, instrumentation

I am designing a signal conditioning circuit to remove all frequency under 20Hz for some EMG measurement. I have several questions about the circuit design:

1. For the instrumentation amplifier, should I go with higher gain (i.e. around X100) or lower gain (i.e. around x10)? I read several papers and they have competing designs (some said the lower gain is advantageous because the filter will not be saturated by the DC offset, whereas others said that the higher gain has better CMRR) (Note: I am planning to use INA128)
2. When making a higher order low pass filter, should I cascade multiple filters with gradual cutoff frequency or can I just cascade filters with the same cutoff frequencies over and over? (i.e. I want to remove all frequency under20Hz using a fourth order filter, then should I use filters with cutoff frequencies 30, 27, 23, 20Hz or just 20Hz x4)
3. When using op-amps with multiple channels, is the gain specified by the datasheet the overall gain of the op-amp or the gain of a single op-amp?
4. How to calculate the total gain of multiple cascaded filters in a circuit?

Thank you so much. Happy New Year!

Comment: You can certainly cascade filters with the same cutoff frequency, however, this changes the transfer function. Let's say your filter has a 3dB point of 20 Hz. If you cascade two of them, then the signal will be down by 6dB at 20 Hz. For three it will be 9dB, etc. In order to actually DESIGN a filter, you normally would specify how much attenuation you need at at least two points. For example, max atten of 3dB at 20 Hz. Min atten of 20 dB at 10 Hz. Something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**About dual and quad opamp ICs**: the performance specs such as offset voltage, open loop gain and gain-bandwidth product are given for one opamp.

**About the instrumentation amp gain**: You must know how much DC offset and how strong signals can be expected from the sensors in your application. This is the very basic data for succesful design. You must do experiments and measurements for them if you cannot find it from reliable sources. Most of us do not know enough about EMG for good numerical answer. I believe it would be useful to include a preamplifier with differential output into the sensor. But that's only an opinion, I have no numerical facts.

**About the filter:**

Cascading second order filters to get higher order filtering is a good idea because it gives good control over the effects of component tolerances and make steep filter slopes possible. Cascading first order filters cannot provide steep filtering. That's a mathematical fact. To see it one must be able to understand transfer functions with complex numbers.

Cascading several identical well designed filters isn't the right way to good performance. It can be useful if you cannot perform proper design procedures or the specs are too fuzzy. It's possible to iterate towards a good result by experimenting altough there's no quarantee for it. Simulation makes succesful development by experiments possible in practice.

Total gain of cascaded filter blocks is the product of single block gains assuming the the effect of loading variations can be negleted (in decibels the gains must be summed). If you have passive circuits, the loading varies radically and the resulted gain is very complex to calculate.

Filter design starts from the wanted filtering effect. To be able to specify it you must have good data of expected interferencing noise signals and of the signal which you want to keep clean. The wanted filtering effect spec is numerical:

- passband limit frequency
- allowed passband gain variation
- stopband limit frequency
- wanted minimum stopband attenuation
- wanted special frequency attenuations (for ex. you surely want to specify some special treatment for the mains ac frequency)
- allowed passband phase nonlinearity

These are the limit specs for the wanted mathematical transfer function. Plenty of good transfer function models (Butterworth, Tsebychev, Bessel, Elliptic) has been developed and you must select which fits to your spec and calculate the parameters for it. This all is very basic stuff which has been well documented in filter synthesis textbooks tens of years ago. You can also find plenty of software to do all calculations. There's software that also help in the next step.

The transfer function must be splitted to second order blocks which can be built using common opamp filter circuits. There are also available special ICs for filters.

Finally you must simulate the design - especially the effect of the component tolerances and noise. Noise can be also measured from a test circuit, but the tolerances must be simulated if you are going to build several units.

Comment: EMG can reach 100mV RMS on large muscles, though it can be very very small on tiny muscles, especially for electrodes at some distance.  It will depend, obviously, on whether you're using surface electrodes or electrodes buried in the muscle (which will always be large signals, as muscle is active tissue).  I like to leave headroom for at least 150mV of total electrode offset.

Comment: @ScottSeidman Thanks! That's essential data+ for us who haven't done anything serious in that field. If you want to share something as an answer, at least I want to read it.